# Average PAGE access time OS

Tags: operating-system

In a paged memory, the page hit ratio is .35

Time required to access a page in secondary memory is 100 ns.

Time required to access a page in primary memory is 10 ns.

what is the average time required to access a page ?

in what way can i answer this question?

Answer (score 2):

> .35 hit * 10 ns = 3.5 ns
>
> .65 miss * (10 ns + 100 ns) = 71.5 ns
>
> 71.5 ns + 3.5 ns = 75 ns average

Answer (score 1):

hit ratio is .35
so page fault rate=.65

```
Page access time=(1-page fault)*(Time required to access a page in primary memory)

                 +(page fault)Miss penalty
```

(1-.65)*10

**+**

(.65)*100

3.5+ 65=

**68.5**

Thank you Jason